# Where is the FilterSet for django-filter located?

Tags: python, django, django-filter

The documentation shows

We have a number of fields and we want to let our users filter based on the price or the release_date. We create a FilterSet for this:

```
import django_filters

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['price', 'release_date']
```

Where does this code get placed to create a FilterSet? Is it in models or views? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wherever you want, I mean models.py, views.py or even a new file called filters.py. Because you will use that filter in views.py, so you can import the filters from everywhere in your project.
For me, I think a file filters.py in the app is the best place.

So in your views.py import the filters like this:

```
from .filters import ProductFilter
```